# How to add merge subarrays of two multi-dimensional arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-merge, sub-array

Sorry about such an easy question but I am new to PHP.
I am trying to add the `isInStock` keys and values from this array:

`$stock` array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => name of item 1
            [price] => 45.00
            [colour] => Neon yellow
            [image] => http://images1
            [url] => http://url1
            [productid] => 7985894
            [variants] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [variantId] => 7986029
                            [isInStock] => 1
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [variantId] => 7986070
                            [isInStock] => 1
                        )
                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [variantId] => 7985916
                            [isInStock] => 1
                        )
                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [variantId] => 7985929
                            [isInStock] => 1
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [variantId] => 7985918
                            [isInStock] => 1
                        )
                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [variantId] => 7985935
                            [isInStock] => 1
                        )
                    [6] => Array
                        (
                            [variantId] => 7985945
                            [isInStock] => 1
                        )
                    [7] => Array
                        (
                            [variantId] => 7985994
                            [isInStock] => 1
                        )
                )
            [productId] => 7985894
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => name of item 2
            [price] => 45.00
            [colour] => Multi
            [image] => http://images
            [url] => http://url
            [productid] => 8040851
            [variants] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [variantId] => 8040898
                            [isInStock] => 1
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [variantId] => 8041115
                            [isInStock] => 1
                        )
                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [variantId] => 8040904
                            [isInStock] => 1
                        )
                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [variantId] => 8041132
                            [isInStock] => 1
                        )
                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [variantId] => 8041015
                            [isInStock] => 1
                        )
                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [variantId] => 8040942
                            [isInStock] => 1
                        )
                    [6] => Array
                        (
                            [variantId] => 8040954
                            [isInStock] => 1
                        )
                    [7] => Array
                        (
                            [variantId] => 8040990
                            [isInStock] => 1
                        )
                )
            [productId] => 8040851
        )
```

and put them in this array under each `size` according to the `variantId` value if they both match.

`$data` array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => name 1 
            [price] => 45.00
            [colour] => Neon yellow
            [image] => http://url
            [url] => http://url1
            [productid] => 7985894
            [variants] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [variantId] => 7986029
                            [size] => US 0
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [variantId] => 7986070
                            [size] => US 2
                        )
                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [variantId] => 7985916
                            [size] => US 4
                        )
                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [variantId] => 7985929
                            [size] => US 6
                        )
                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [variantId] => 7985918
                            [size] => US 8
                        )
                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [variantId] => 7985935
                            [size] => US 10
                        )
                    [6] => Array
                        (
                            [variantId] => 7985945
                            [size] => US 12
                        )
                    [7] => Array
                        (
                            [variantId] => 7985994
                            [size] => US 14
                        )
                )
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => name 1
            [price] => 45.00
            [colour] => Multi
            [image] => http://url
            [url] => http://url
            [productid] => 8040851
            [variants] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [variantId] => 8040898
                            [size] => US 0
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [variantId] => 8041115
                            [size] => US 2
                        )
                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [variantId] => 8040904
                            [size] => US 4
                        )
                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [variantId] => 8041132
                            [size] => US 6
                        )
                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [variantId] => 8041015
                            [size] => US 8
                        )
                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [variantId] => 8040942
                            [size] => US 10
                        )
                    [6] => Array
                        (
                            [variantId] => 8040954
                            [size] => US 12
                        )
                    [7] => Array
                        (
                            [variantId] => 8040990
                            [size] => US 14
                        )
                )
        )
```

I have been trying to solve this for a while now, but I keep getting stuck. I can assign individual values but can't get it to do the whole array. Any help would be appreciated.

I would like my resulting array to be like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => name 1 
            [price] => 45.00
            [colour] => Neon yellow
            [image] => http://url
            [url] => http://url1
            [productid] => 7985894
            [variants] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [variantId] => 7986029
                            [size] => US 0
                            [isInStock] => 1
                        )    
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [variantId] => 7986070
                            [size] => US 2
                            [isInStock] => 1
                        )    
                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [variantId] => 7985916
                            [size] => US 4
                            [isInStock] => 1
                        )    
                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [variantId] => 7985929
                            [size] => US 6
                            [isInStock] => 1
                        )    
                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [variantId] => 7985918
                            [size] => US 8
                            [isInStock] => 1
                        )    
                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [variantId] => 7985935
                            [size] => US 10
                            [isInStock] => 1
                        )    
                    [6] => Array
                        (
                            [variantId] => 7985945
                            [size] => US 12
                            [isInStock] => 1
                        )    
                    [7] => Array
                        (
                            [variantId] => 7985994
                            [size] => US 14
                            [isInStock] => 1
                        )    
                )    
        )    
    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => name 1
            [price] => 45.00
            [colour] => Multi
            [image] => http://url
            [url] => http://url
            [productid] => 8040851
            [variants] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [variantId] => 8040898
                            [size] => US 0
                            [isInStock] => 1
                        )    
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [variantId] => 8041115
                            [size] => US 2
                            [isInStock] => 1
                        )    
                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [variantId] => 8040904
                            [size] => US 4
                            [isInStock] => 1
                        )    
                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [variantId] => 8041132
                            [size] => US 6
                            [isInStock] => 1
                        )    
                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [variantId] => 8041015
                            [size] => US 8
                            [isInStock] => 1
                        )    
                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [variantId] => 8040942
                            [size] => US 10
                            [isInStock] => 1
                        )    
                    [6] => Array
                        (
                            [variantId] => 8040954
                            [size] => US 12
                            [isInStock] => 1
                        )    
                    [7] => Array
                        (
                            [variantId] => 8040990
                            [size] => US 14
                            [isInStock] => 1
                        )    
                )    
        )
```

So far I have tried `array_merge` which doesn't put the values in the right place.
I have tried this `$data['isInstock'] = $stock[0]['variants'][0]['variantId'];` which also won't work.

Comment: What exactly have you been trying? In addition to showing what output you expect, show what you have tried so far - and where you got stuck.

Comment: You should get in the habit of [accepting answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) that provides you with the best solution.  
This website works both ways, and if you don't give back to the people that help you, you won't be getting much help in the future.

Comment: Didn't know about accepting answers until you pointed it out. I hope as I get better I can help others out in future as well. I have so far tried array_merge, array_combine and array_push.

Comment: @adamp Will `$stock` and `$data` ALWAYS have the same length? or it possible that one of the arrays will have more subarrays?  If one of them is always going to be equal to or larger than the other, this information is important in the process.  Also, does `$stock` actually need both `productid` and `productId`?  This seems like a simple redundancy to omit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, it takes a fair amount of iterating/preparation to get your two arrays ready for use with `array_merge_recursive()`.  I'll admit, I'm not proud of the convolution in my method.  The major factor in all this is that `array_merge_recursive()` only "plays nicely" with non-numeric indexes, so I had to replace your numerically indexed keys with relative id values within the arrays.  I'll do my best to explain my steps, but again, it's not pretty... ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b94252d5250f28988d01bba69de2794b79773f4c))

Step #1: Prepare `$stock` array:

```
foreach($stock as $subarray){
    $new_stock["#{$subarray['productid']}"]=$subarray;  // replace outer key
    $new_variants=[];                                   // declare a fresh array
    foreach($subarray['variants'] as $varsub){
        $new_variants["#{$varsub['variantId']}"]['isInStock']=$varsub['isInStock'];  // one element only
        // omitting variantId element this time as the next array will offer it.
    }
    $new_stock["#{$subarray['productid']}"]['variants']=$new_variants;
}
```

Step #2: Prepare `$data` array & merge:

```
foreach($data as $subarray){
    $new_data["#{$subarray['productid']}"]=$subarray;  // replace outer key
    $new_variants=[];                                  // declare a fresh array
    foreach($subarray['variants'] as $varsub){
        $new_variants["#{$varsub['variantId']}"]=$varsub; // both elements from variants
    }
    $new_data["#{$subarray['productid']}"]['variants']=array_values(array_merge_recursive($new_variants,$new_stock["#{$subarray['productid']}"]['variants']));
    // new variants subarray has been merged, re-indexed, and written to $new_data
}
```

Step #3: re-index outer array keys, and display:

```
$result=array_values($new_data);    
var_export($result);
```

---

The bulk of the array preparations is to generate unique id's for the outer and inner arrays (in both `$stock` & `$data`).  This permits the array_merge to isolate the related `productid`s and recursively merge the `variant` elements.

If these two arrays are being generated from a database, then my high recommendation is to utilize available database functionality to merge this data instead of php.

For a simple example of how `array_merge_recursive()` works here's a small [demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ead67c2625ecf45d2a64330df61a53fb85d9a29b).  Experiment with the keys in either of the arrays.  If you so-much-as remove the `#` from the numeric string, `array_merge_recursive()` will assume that it's dealing with numeric indexes and mince things up.  My technique to preserve your id's as strings was to prepend the `#`, but it could have been done by adding any of a range of non-digit characters to the key value.